# how handle events on every individual entry

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
e1=Entry(root)
e1.pack()
e2=Entry(root)
e2.pack()


def test(x):
    if x==1:            # if event on entry e1 
        print 'e1 event' # do some thing
    elif x==2:            # also if event on entry e2    
        print 'e2 event'  # do some thing else
    else: print 'no event' 

root.bind_class("Entry","<FocusOut>",test(2)) #this can be some thing you suggest to me
root.bind_class("Entry","<FocusOut>",test(1)) # can be some thing you suggest to me   


root.mainloop()
```

How to do things on comments ? I want program to which entry has the cursor to type and when focus out with tab key so can do some thing different from on other entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from Tkinter import *

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

def test(x):    
    #print "I'm in event:", x
    if x == 1:            # if event on entry e1 
        print 'e1 event' # do some thing
    elif x == 2:            # also if event on entry e2    
        print 'e2 event'  # do some thing else
    else: 
        print 'no event' 

def test1(x):
    test(1)

def test2(x):
    test(2)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

root=Tk()

e1=Entry(root)
e1.pack()

e2=Entry(root)
e2.pack()

root.bind_class(e1, "<FocusOut>", test1) #this can be some thing you suggest to me
root.bind_class(e2, "<FocusOut>", test2) # can be some thing you suggest to me   

root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT:**

you can bind also this way:

```
e1.bind("<FocusOut>", test1)
e2.bind("<FocusOut>", test2)
```

but always give only function name without its arguments.

Function have to get 1 argument to get Event Object

```
def test1(x):
    print x # <Tkinter.Event instance at 0xb74a6fcc>
    test(1)
```

**EDIT:**

Start learning object-oriented programming to make "cleaner" programs - more structured.

```
from Tkinter import *

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class MainWindow():

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.e1 = Entry(root)
        self.e1.pack()

        self.e2 = Entry(root)
        self.e2.pack()

        self.e1.bind("<FocusOut>", self.test1)
        self.e2.bind("<FocusOut>", self.test2)

    #-------------------

    def test(self, x):
        if x == 1:           
            print 'e1 event'
        elif x == 2:
            print 'e2 event'
        else:
            print 'no event' 

    #-------------------

    def test1(self, x):
        print x
        self.test(1)

    #-------------------

    def test2(self, x):
        self.test(2)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

root = Tk()
MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT:**

Last version - with one function using event object

```
from Tkinter import *

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class MainWindow():

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.e1 = Entry(root)
        self.e1.pack()

        self.e2 = Entry(root)
        self.e2.pack()

        self.e1.bind("<FocusOut>", self.test)
        self.e2.bind("<FocusOut>", self.test)
        # or
        # root.bind_class("Entry", "<FocusOut>", self.test)

    #-------------------

    def test(self, event):
        if event.widget == self.e1:
            #print "e1:", event.widget.get()
            print "e1:", self.e1.get()

        if event.widget == self.e2:
            #print "e2:", event.widget.get()
            print "e2:", self.e2.get()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

root = Tk()
MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

More about events: [Tkinter Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)